# How to silence 'Expected a type' Xcode compiler warnings?

Tags: objective-c, class

Is there any way to silence Xcode compiler warnings because of unknown types like with @class?
I defined a type in a single .h file that can be reused throughout the app:

```
#ifndef Apsiape_InterfaceDefinitions_h
#define Apsiape_InterfaceDefinitions_h

#define COLOR_ALERT_RED [UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:0.3 blue:0.3 alpha:1]
...

typedef enum  {
    BYEdgeTypeNone = 0,
    BYEdgeTypeTop,
    BYEdgeTypeLeft,
    BYEdgeTypeBottom,
    BYEdgeTypeRight
} BYEdgeType;

#endif
```

And one of my classes uses the `BYEdgeType` type for a custom protocol in the .h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol BYPullScrollViewDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)pullScrollView:(UIScrollView*)pullScrollView didScrollToPage:(NSInteger)page;
- (void)pullScrollView:(UIScrollView*)pullScrollView didDetectPullingAtEdge:(BYEdgeType)edge;

@end
```

I want my `InterfaceDefinitions.h` file to be in the .m file of my class, but if I don't import it in the .m of the class Xcode (of course) complains that it "Expected a type" (BYEdgeType). How can I silence this warning @class-style?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't understand.  If XYZ.h refers to ABC.h, just import ABC.h into XYZ.h.

Answer (score 0):

Is the protocol defined in a header (`.h`) file? If so, to use enums and `#defines` in the .h file, you'll have to import the header with those definitions in that `.h` file.